# How do I print the square root symbol?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

[image]

How to print the square root symbol like picture in wpf ?

Please help me a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
 Console.WriteLine( "Square root = \u221A" );
```